# Error while serializing the list in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

The error I am getting is
`AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`

What I am trying to do is to get the `VAttribute Objects` related to given class and the `AttributeValues` related to `PAttribute` object and convert into a list ?

I think The error was while serializing the `attribute_data_values`.

```
class_id = request.GET.get('class_id')
print(class_id)

qs = VAttribute.objects.filter(class=class_id)
print(qs, '')

attribute_data = []
attribute_data_values = []

for obj in qs:
    attribute_data.append(obj.attribute)
    attribute_data_values.append(obj.attribute.attributevalues_set.all()) # the problem is here
data = serializers.serialize('json', attribute_data)
values = serializers.serialize('json', attribute_data_values)

data = {
    'attribute': data,
    'values': values
}

return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

These are my models

```
class VAttribute(models.Model):
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(PAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute_values = models.ManyToManyField(AttributeValues)

class PAttribute(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class AttributeValues(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(PAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Try `qs = VAttribute.objects.filter(class=class_id).first()`

Comment: @ShivamJha I need all the objects not only the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess what you're ending up with in `attribute_data_values` is a list of lists but you're treating it as a flat list. If that's the case, instead of `attribute_data_values.append(obj.attribute.attributevalues_set.all())`
try `attribute_data_values += obj.attribute.attributevalues_set.all()`